# Cross Browser positioning issue with Chrome and Firefox

Tags: css, cross-browser

I was hoping someone could help me figure out what to do about a browser inconsistency issue between Safari/Chrome and Firefox.

Here's a screenshot (the one on the left is chrome/right is Firefox):  http://drp.ly/QVv2T

Here's the structure: http://drp.ly/QW47y

The css:

```
inside-wrapper {
    position:relative;
    min-height:320px;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;
    width:785px;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
}

select p a {
    display:block;
    clear:both;
    margin:0;
    padding:7px 0 6px 10px;
}

select ul {
    position:absolute;
    top:162px;
    left:1px;
    width:396px;
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help and let me know if I can post more info.

Comment: Well yeah it would be nice to see the HTML that generates it. A little drawing that shows the layout doesn't help us at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to those who took the time to look this over - I realize I was very vague and didn't provide nearly enough information.

I was able to find a fix.  The problem was the main div that encompassed all of this needed to be set to position:relative and I instead had the parent of the whole thing set to relative.

Thanks everyone for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your CSS I noticed you put a `<ul>` inside a `<select>` tag. That's not a valid combination.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, It's not a form select html, but just an ID name (I had to take out the # sign because it was causing a weird formatting issue with Textile)